# Call to connect() fails with EINVAL

Tags: c, sockets, udp, posix, udpclient

When calling `connect` in my program below, it fails with `errno` of 22 (`EINVAL`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc != 3) { /* usage */
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: talk address port\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char* address = argv[1];
    char* port = argv[2];

    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *servinfo;
    struct addrinfo *clientinfo;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    int gai_res = getaddrinfo(address, port, &hints, &servinfo);

    if(gai_res) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to resolve remote address: %s\n",
            gai_strerror(gai_res));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    gai_res = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &clientinfo);

    if(gai_res) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to resolve local address: %s\n",
            gai_strerror(gai_res));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    int socket_fd = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype,
        servinfo->ai_protocol);

    if(socket_fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open socket to remote host: %s\n",
            strerror(errno));
        freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int bind_res = bind(socket_fd, clientinfo->ai_addr, clientinfo->ai_addrlen);

    if(bind_res == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to bind to socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int connect_res = connect(socket_fd, servinfo->ai_addr,
        servinfo->ai_addrlen);

    if(connect_res == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ssize_t bytes_sent = send(socket_fd, "Hello", 7, 0);

    if(bytes_sent == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to send to remote host: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Sent message to %s on port %s\n", address, port);

    close(socket_fd);
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
$ gcc talk.c -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic -std=gnu99 -g3 -o talk
$ ./talk 192.168.0.16 3301
Failed to connect to socket: Invalid argument
```

When I inspect the contents of `servinfo` in GDB, everything seems fine:

```
$ gdb talk -q
Reading symbols from talk...done.
(gdb) b main.c:63
Breakpoint 1 at 0x13fb: file main.c, line 63.
(gdb) run 192.168.0.16 3301
Starting program: /home/foo/dev/tmp/talk/talk 192.168.0.16 3301

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe328) at main.c:63
63      int connect_res = connect(socket_fd, servinfo->ai_addr,
(gdb) p servinfo
$1 = (struct addrinfo *) 0x555555559260
(gdb) p *servinfo
$2 = {ai_flags = 0, ai_family = 2, ai_socktype = 2, ai_protocol = 17, ai_addrlen = 16, ai_addr = 0x555555559290, ai_canonname = 0x0, ai_next = 0x0}
(gdb) p servinfo->ai_addr
$3 = (struct sockaddr *) 0x555555559290
(gdb) p *(servinfo->ai_addr)
$4 = {sa_family = 2, sa_data = "\f\345\300\250\000\020\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}
```

Note that calling `connect` on UDP sockets is well-defined and is done (in this case, at least) to allow easy use of `send` and `recv` (rather than their datagram counterparts).

Which of the parameters to `connect` would be invalid in this case?

Comment: Not an answer but your message "Failed to connect to socket" is not correct. You failed to connect *this socket* to a remote *address.*

Comment: I've compiled and run your program, seems to work ok. Is this Linux? `strace` output might help.

Comment: Cast `servinfo->ai_addr` to `struct sockaddr_in*` and make sure its `sin_addr` and `sin_port` fields are correct.

Comment: I suggest there is something wrong with the port. Try setting `hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV;` to force it to be treated as numeric, and check the value you get back to ensure it isn't zero.

Comment: @MarkNunberg This is running on OpenBSD 6.7.